# jquery on click ID only works for first output

Tags: jquery, function, click

For a dashboard where there is a list of links I want to perform some actions if someone clicks the delete button. But somehow it only responds on the first link with id="delete_link". What do I need to change to let this work for all of the lniks?

Php code:

```
if($count < 1) {
        echo "There are no links in this category yet";
    }

while($link = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo "<li><a href='" . $link->url . "' TARGET='_BLANK'>" . $link->title . "</a>";
    if($_SESSION['role'] == '2') {
        echo "<span style='float:right;opacity:0.85;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span><span style='float:right;opacity:0.85;margin-right:10px;' id='delete_link' data-linkid='" . $link->id . "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>";
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>
        </div>
            </div>";
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#delete_link').click(function(){
        var dataId = $(this).data('linkid');
        var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this link?");
        if(confirmDelete == true) {
            alert(dataId);
            // $.ajax({
                // type: "POST",
                // url: "delete_link.php",
                // data: ""
            // })
        }else {
            alert("FALSE");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a `<span id="delete_link">` in a `while` loop. Get rid of it or switch it for a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code . assign class 'delete_link' to elements instead of id.

```
    echo "<span style='float:right;opacity:0.85;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span><span style='float:right;opacity:0.85;margin-right:10px;' class='delete_link' data-linkid='" . $link->id . "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>";
```

id must be unique in a DOM. so event only work on i element who have same id.

also you need to check [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach event to dynamically created element. Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click','.delete_link',function(){
      var dataId = $(this).data('linkid');
      var confirmDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this link?");
    if(confirmDelete == true) {
        alert(dataId);
        // $.ajax({
            // type: "POST",
            // url: "delete_link.php",
            // data: ""
        // })
    }else {
        alert("FALSE");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In HTML Ids must be unique. If you have multiple elements, you should use [classes](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

```
echo "<span class='delete_link' data-linkid='" . $link->id . "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>";
```

*Script*, Use [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind event

```
$('.delete_link').click(function(){
   //Your code will work fine
});
```